# Can we disable/enable MIUI optimization in Redmi devices

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui, redmi-device

I have one use case where we have to turn off MIUI optimization on Redmi devices programatically. Is there any way to do this from an Android app programmatically on Redmi devices?